# Loading stylesheet from various locations

Tags: css, jsp, properties, stylesheet

I have not worked on JSPs for a long time and I'm not sure how to approach this issue.

I have this following code which tries to load a stylesheet in a page in the following way-

In JSP-

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href='<bean:message key="properties.file.key" bundle="propertiesFile" />' />
```

In `propertiesFile.properties` file-

```
properties.file.key=//dummy.website.com/absolute/path/of/cssFile.css
```

The same `css` file is downloaded and available locally as well.

Now, I want to fetch the `cssFile.css` from the `dummy.website.com` first, if I'm unable to do it (due to various reasons like the `css` may not be available anymore or the website may be blocked by the browser, etc...), I want to fetch it from the local location. Is there anyway I could do that?

Comment: i dont quite understand _your problem in fetching the css from local drive_ Have you tried it ?

Comment: You wanted to link file ay runtime? Dynamically?

Comment: I can fetch it from the local hard drive. But, I want to first try to load by giving the static location of the css available in the website, if i'm unable to find it, I should be able to fetch it from the local drive. That's what I intend to do.